# Apache Directory Listing, Including "Default" Files

Tags: apache, configuration, apache2

To enable a directory listing, we'd use this in Apache:

```
Options Indexes
```

How to list the directory content, *including* the default file that Apache serves when a directory is requested i.e. `DirectoryIndex index.html`?

Ideally, we can set this up per virtual host. My vhost file looks something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin my@email.com
  DocumentRoot /some/path/
  ...
  <Directory />
    Options Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `DirectoryIndex` directive to a value, that might never occur as a filename on your filesystem:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin my@email.com
  DocumentRoot /some/path/
  ...
  <Directory />
    Options Indexes
    DirectoryIndex !
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But once somebody adds a file named `!` it will be served by apache instead of showing the directory index list. So it's more or less an odd workaround instead of a proper solution.

Comment: `DirectoryIndex disabled` will be available in next release of apache2, it's already available in unstable v2.3 http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_dir.html